# error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'inet_ntoa'

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I have tried looking for ways to get the *IP address* of the client, done with the declaration of variables and the library (using windows so winsock2.h). I also used `16` instead of `INET_ADDRSTRLEN` because it wasn't executing with it

```
inet_ntoa(AF_INET, &(client_addr.sin_addr), addr, 16);
printf("The IP address of client is: %s\n",addr);
```

can anyone please help with it?

Comment: `inet_ntoa` only takes one param, and it's not an address family. [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-inet_ntoa)

Answer (score 2):

You use arguments that are usually passed to `inet_ntop` and pass them to `inet_ntoa`, which takes just a `struct in_addr` argument.

You should not use `inet_ntoa` if `inet_ntop` is available. But it's probably even better to use `getnameinfo`.